# SQL-Select with decimal field not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, decimal

I have a table with a decimal field in Postgres
The value of the field is 39.95

I try to make a SQL-Query to get all records with value 39.95

This is my code:

```
SELECT CR_Sale.id , CR_Sale.sale_date, ROUND(CR_Sale.sale_bruto_total, 2) 
    AS sale_bruto_total, CR_Sale.sale_ticket
FROM crm_CR_Sale CR_Sale
WHERE sale_bruto_total = 39.95
ORDER BY sale_timestamp DESC;
```

When I execute the query no results are found.
If I change my code to

```
WHERE sale_bruto_total <= 39.95
```

I get a result and can see the records with value 39.95

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: For starters, are you looking for 39.55 or 39.95? [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/398fa/1)

Comment: sorry, it was a typing error, correct is 39.95.

Comment: What is the data type of `sale_bruto_total`? Sounds as if it is not defined as `decimal` but as `float` (or `double`): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5cbb09/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as follow:-

```
SELECT CR_Sale.id , CR_Sale.sale_date, ROUND(CR_Sale.sale_bruto_total, 2) 
    AS sale_bruto_total, CR_Sale.sale_ticket
FROM crm_CR_Sale CR_Sale
WHERE sale_bruto_total = CAST(39.95 AS dec(5,2))
ORDER BY sale_timestamp DESC;
```

**Note**:- 'sale_bruto_total' column should be decimal type

Answer (score 0):

The number `39.95` is not a `decimal` value but a `float` and then you can't make equality comparisons due to the internal precision of `float`s (this being the reason why there is the `decimal` data type in the first place) so you have to add an explicit cast:

```
sale_bruto_total = 39.95::decimal(5,2)
```

Also, if the value of `sale_bruto_total` is *exactly* `39.95` because the field is defined as a `decimal` with two decimals after the dot, then you do not need the `round()` function in the select list. On the other hand, if there are more decimals then you need to use the `round()` function in the filter too. So either:

```
SELECT id, sale_date, round(sale_bruto_total, 2) AS sale_bruto_total, sale_ticket
FROM crm_CR_Sale
WHERE round(sale_bruto_total, 2) = 39.95::decimal(5,2)
ORDER BY sale_timestamp DESC;
```

or

```
SELECT id, sale_date, sale_bruto_total, sale_ticket
FROM crm_CR_Sale
WHERE sale_bruto_total = 39.95::decimal(5,2)
ORDER BY sale_timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: If the column is defined as `decimal` the casting shouldn't be necessary: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5cbb09/1